# how to write select query for set matching

Tags: mysql, sql

Please help me out with idea to find out the solution. 
i am unable to think about subquery

SELECT name FROM client where assest_id IN(?subquery?)

[image]

Comment: Firstly, is it SQL Server or MySQL? Secondly, that looks like YOUR homework. Thirdly, text question is much better than an image.

Comment: i just want to know the query either in sql or Mysql as i am an android developer so i forgot lots of things in SQL query. next its not my home work i am stuck in a real life problem that is different but aspect is same as i have asked. I have mentioned it in query that tables are indicative. And really very sorry i was unable to format table in query area thats why i have used image. Thanks for the review

Comment: @RQube the first question will give Tom and Philip as the answer as both have 2 room apartment and byke

Comment: @Gone since philip is also having car so it won't qualify in result set (result would have clients having exactly the same set not its superset)

Comment: ok and if asset_id in client_table is primary key then it shouldn't repeat.1 john 101 2 Tina 101

Comment: @Gone you are right, but i have repeated the values to describe its not unique inside client table. i have designed in this way because there is probability that multiple client would have same set of assets so i can assign same asset id to every client having equal asset set thus it result in less data redundancy in client-asset table. like jhon and tina having same asset-set thats why both are having asset_id 101.

Comment: Ok.. Anyways i didnt use PK FK constraints in the query..so it would work fine..Hope the answer helped u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For the 1st question**

```
select name from client where asset_id in(
select asset_id from client_asset where
asset_desc='2'
intersect
select asset_id from client_asset where
asset_id not in (select asset_id from client_asset where
                 asset_name not in ('apartment','byke')));
```

For the first question first I have fetched the `asset_id` with 2room and `intersected` it with the asset_id which have only `byke and apartment` as their assets. This is used as the subquery to by the containment statement to fetch the `asset_id`

**For the 2nd question**

```
select name from client where asset_id in
(select asset_id from client_asset where
asset_desc>='2' and asset_name='apartment'
intersect
select asset_id from client_asset where
asset_name='car');
```

This query is self explainatory and works on similar grounds

Comment: Ah, yes, forgot to remove my comment but I already removed my down vote.  It wasn't correct before.

Comment: It's not my question ;)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time @Gone +1 from my side :)